# ENVI EX reviews?

Tags: remote-sensing, envi

Does anyone have a review of ENVI EX?  I am wondering how well the Feature Extraction and Image Classification workflows function.

Answer (score 4):

based on my experience, envi ex is good if you don't have much time and need the data "quickly", if you're using good resolution rasters. in low-res rasters, the regular version, imho, is much better, because you have a better control of the procedure.

if you try the various extraction methods with the same raster in envi and envi ex, the results you obtain in regular envi are more accurate than the one's from envi ex.

edit: in the first line, i meant "envi ex", not "envi"...

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, ENVI EX provides a rather simplistic method for performing feature extraction using object-based image analysis. I investigated using ENVI EX for a project involving image segmentation and classification, and decided that there was not enough configurability for my needs.

Instead, I find the [eCognition](http://www.ecognition.com/) provides a far more configurable (albeit far more expensive) piece of software which will allow you to segment with various parameters, and then perform very complex image classifications involving user-defined metrics and fuzzy parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, ENVI Ex is good in sence if you donot have sofisticaed software like eCognition. But it have very less parameter to for user control. Segmentation results are satisfactory but classification are not good.